# Purpose of negative indices in time series

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

In the book *Time-series analysis by Hamilton* we find the following passage:

A time series is a collection of observations indexed by the date of each observation. Usually we have collected data beginning at some particular date ( say $t = 1$) and ending at another (say, $t = T$) in the following fashion:

$(y_{1} ,y_{2} ..., y_{T})$

We often imagine that we could have obtained earlier observations $(y_{0} , y_{-1} , y_{-2}...)$ or later observations $(y_{T + 1} , y_{T + 2} , y_{T + 3}...)$ had the process been observed for more time.

Typically, a time series $\{y_{t}\}^{\infty}_{t = -\infty}$ is identified by describing the $t$-th element of the time series.

Why do we need negative indices in our time series? Is it correct to say that $y_{-1}$ is the $-1\:th$ element of the time series $y_{t}$? That sounds weird and wrong. Is the negative indices only there to denote unobserved observations in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that we might potentially want to look *arbitrarily far back in time* and so we set up the mathematics of our problem in a way that allows us to do that.  This doesn't even hinge on making $t=1$ the current time --- even if we were to take some higher positive value $t_0 > 1$ as the current time, if we wanted to look back $t_0+2$ time periods before the current time we would get a negative index.

If you were to proceed in the contrary fashion, by limiting the time-series to non-negative time indices then your time index would be *bounded from below*, so there would always be a limit on how far backward you could look from any time period.  We generally don't wish to limit ourselves in this way *a priori* and so it is usual to define time series over the *unbounded* set of time values $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is it the correct practice to refer to $y_{-1}$ as the $-1th$ element of the time series $y_{t}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Could $y_{-1}$ be part of an observed sample or does an observed sample always run from 1 up to some value $T$?

Comment: The meaning of the time point $t=0$ is arbitrary, so you can define the time indices however you want --- in the case where we observe a set of $T$ consecutive values then *by convention* we set these either to be the indices $t=1,...,T$ or $t=0,...,T-1$ (depending on the what source you look at).